# Line break after \item, vertical spacing

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

First, my example:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\codeitem[1]{
    \item[{
        \framebox[\textwidth][l]{
        \tt
        {#1}
        }
     }]
    }

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{description}
        \codeitem{+ here() : void}
            Followed by some paragraphs of text. Do you see the text is too near to the box?
        \codeitem{\# there() : void}
            I somehow have to add vertical space here.
    \end{description}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

This renders as follows:
[image: too little space after the box]

I think the idea is clear. Alas, there's too little vertical space after the description label. How can I set the vertical space between the item label and its text?
I've tried setting `\vspace{11mm}` but this has the same effect as using `topsep=11mm` or `partopsep=11mm` on the description. It only increases the distance between list items or the list and the paragraph before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\codeitem[1]{%
    \item[{%
        \framebox[\textwidth][l]{%
        \normalfont\ttfamily
        #1%
        }\vspace{3pt}%
     }]
    }

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{description}[style=nextline]
        \codeitem{+ here() : void}
            Followed by some paragraphs of text. Do you see the text is too near to the box?
        \codeitem{\# there() : void}
            I somehow have to add vertical space here.
    \end{description}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Note the `style=nextline` option to avoid overfull boxes and also the `%` to protect end-of-lines and avoid they produce space in output. The command `\tt` is obsolete and deprecated: use `\ttfamily`. The `\normalfont` command is to avoid requesting for boldface typewriter type.

[image]

A refinement might be as follows:

```
\newcommand\codeitem[1]{%
    \item[{%
        \framebox[\textwidth][l]{%
        \ttfamily\ttstrut
        #1%
        }\vspace{3pt}%
     }]
    }

\newcommand{\ttstrut}{%
  \vrule width0pt
         height1.5ex
         depth.5ex
}
```

With this, we'd get (magnified for better showing the effect, adding also a letter with a descender)

[image]

The boxes will all have the same total height; the top and bottom of an `x` will have the same distance from top and bottom rule respectively. Ascenders and descenders will occupy the otherwise white space.

Comment: looks good, but if anything in the code happens to have a real descender ("f", "p", "y", ...), the height of the boxes will be noticeably different.  you may want to consider taking that into account.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's a good point. I have not yet happened to get into this special situation. Do you have suggestions concerning different-heighted boxes?

Thank you for your overall notices. It's great to see ´´style=nextline´´ and ´´\vspace´´ do the trick.

Comment: @user2149498 -- if there isn't any instance of a boxed item with a descender, i think i'd stick with this -- it looks nice.  but maybe an alternate form, with `\vphantom{y}` or similar, could be defined for use when a bunch of items that are visually close together includes one or more that contain a descender.  for a multi-page document, maybe this would be a last-pass decision.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'll add a `\ttstrut`.